# ComboBox и DataSource

Tags: c#, .net

Допустим, элементами `ComboBox` являются элементы какого-нибудь `List`, который я получаю из БД и привязываю к `ComboBox` через `DataSource`.

Можно ли добавить в `ComboBox` такой элемент, который будет присутствовать там вне зависимости от того, будет ли он в `DataSource` или нет?

Например, если `ComboBox` использует как какой-то фильтр, то мне пригодился бы вариант *"Все"*.

Получается его каждый раз руками нужно добавлять в `DataSource`?

Comment: WPF или WinForms?

Comment: @VladD, WinForms. Надо сделать так, что бы в ComboBox был такой элемент, который бы не исчезал при подключении DataSource.

Comment: С WinForms у меня нет опыта, может, подтянется кто-нибудь ещё.

Comment: Чем плох вариант при получении `List` просто добавлять в начало элемент _Все_?

Comment: @ExiD, я так и делаю. Но я думал, что есть какой-нибудь другой вариант.

Comment: Я считаю что этот вариант самый оптимальный и понятный. А в случае с фильтром вы можете сделать элемент который сбрасывает фильтр комбобокса. То есть будет работать как "все".

Comment: @iluxa1810 если вас мой ответ совсем не устраивает - будьте добры, отпишите, как вам хочется видеть это решение. Попробую накидать варианты.

Answer (score 2):

Вариант с ручным добавлением записи "Все" - самый быстрый и простой.

Есть вариант посложнее - создаете наследника `ComboBox`, который при изменении коллекции элементов добавляет "Все" автоматически.

Вы, к сожалению, всё так же мучаете `WinForm`, не помню так сразу в нём готовых решений.

Решение в лоб простое:

```
  public class ComboBoxWithAll : ComboBox
  {
    public ComboBoxWithAll()
    {
      this.BindingContextChanged += OnBindingContextChanged;
    }

    private void OnBindingContextChanged(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
      var item = "Все";
      var list = this.DataSource as List<string>;
      if (list != null && list.Any() && list[0] != item)
      {
        list.Insert(0, item);
      }
      OnDataSourceChanged(args);
    }
  }
```

Но стоит иметь в виду, что я тут сделал явные завязки на тип `DataSource` и я меняю его, что в принципе никогда не должны делать контролы.

Если вас это не устраивает - то надо заморачиваться ещё больше, с разделением на реальную коллекцию и отображаемую, ну и тогда уже надо добавлять признак того, что выбран пункт "Все".